# ag-grid master detail expand/collapse functionality

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am working on ag-grid with angular 8 and i need to have a solution like on expand of any master row existing expanded rows should collapse. There should be only single master detail row should be expanded. Does that implementation exists in Ag-grid or any custom implementation needs to be implemented? Can anyone help me on this ?

Answer (score 3):

You just need the `params` or `gridApi` and loop over each `node`.

If you want to expand all:

```js
params.api.forEachNode(node => {
  node.setExpanded(true);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a feature called [Custom Detail](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-master-detail-custom-detail/#custom-detail), but it is only in enterprise (paid) version of the library.

It does not implement collapsing of other rows ou of the box, but that could be implemented with use of [grouping API](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-grouping/#grouping-api).

Comment: Hi @lavor , Thanks for your answer . I am using enterprise version of ag-grid only and i don't find any solution with groupingAPI. if do you have examples can you share with me

Comment: Facing the same issue, if this even supported by the grid??

Answer (score 0):

You need to add custom implementation for this. You can find the below code snippet to expand and collapse all the rows.

```html
  expandCollapseAll() {
    this.gridApi.forEachNode(function (node) {
      node.expanded = !!window.collapsed;
    });
    window.collapsed = !window.collapsed;
    this.gridApi.onGroupExpandedOrCollapsed();
  }
```

You can listen to `rowGroupOpened` event in the ag grid api to know which row node is expanded and you can collase all other nodes.

```html
fromEvent<RowGroupOpenedEvent>(this.agGridApi, 'rowGroupOpened').subscribe(event => {

  const openedNodeId = event.node.id;
  
  this.agGridApi.forEachNode((node) => {
      if(openedNodeId === node.id) {
        return;
      }
      node.expanded = false;
  });
    
  this.agGridApi.onGroupExpandedOrCollapsed();

})
```

To know more about this ag grid feature, read [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/master-detail-custom-detail/#custom-detail-with-grid)